# How to verify the owner of a facebook page id?

Tags: facebook, validation, graph, tabs

I have a tab page app on facebook that allows people show their data from my database on their facebook page.

When setting it up, I need to connect their Page Id on facebook to their User Id in my database, so when a user visits the tab on their page, my app receives the page id, and knows which user id to look up.

My question is how do I verify the owner of a page id so that a random user cannot claim to own a page id and make it point to the wrong user id in our database? I imagine I should send an automated private message to their page, but apparently that feature is no longer available on facebook.

What's the right way to validate them?

Answer (score 0):

You need permission manage_pages and then you use /me/accounts ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/accounts )